# cannot run Prolog application in ProDT in eclipse kepler and juno

Tags: eclipse, prolog, swi-prolog

I've installed ProDT plugin for ide.

It highlights the code, have configuration for Prolog interpreter.

But there is no way to run app.

Also Right Click/ProDT/"Consult in Console" dids nothing.

How to fix that?

Run as/"Run Swi session" menu absent.

I'm using SWI-prolog interpreter.

Comment: Do you have SWI installed?

Comment: Make sure one of the code files in your ProDT project has focus.  I sometimes see the `Run as` menu empty in Eclipse after saving a file etc., but when I click back into the Editor view of the file, then the `Run as` menu populates with the expected options.

Comment: Daniel Lyons, yes. SWI is installed and configured as intepreter used in eclipse.